# Remove Application from itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am an iOS application developer and I am facing a problem with the itunes connect, due to some problems I have rejected the binary of the application in itunes connect.Now that app is showing as "Developer Rejected" state, can I remove this application from itunes connect?

Comment: simple answer, nope. u can add new version to change the status

Comment: You can add new version, why you need to remove ?

Comment: I have already uploaded an another application with different name so i want to remove this

Answer (score -1):

Answer is Yes.

Why you need to remove the app ? If you want to keep the app, you can upload a newer version.

If you don't want to keep that app permanently you can delete it. For deleting an app you need to follow these steps.

- Open the App Details page for the app, as described in To open the App Details page for an app.
- Make sure that the app status allows deletion.
  You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app and the latest version status is one of the following:

  1. Prepare for Submission
  2. Invalid Binary
  3. Developer Rejected
  4. Rejected
  5. Metadata Rejected
  6. Developer Removed From Sale
  7. Removed from Sale

  If your app has a different status, you can delete the app by first rejecting the binary or by removing the app from sale. See Viewing and Changing Your App’s Status and Availability.
- Click the More menu and select Delete App.

  If the Delete App button isn’t displayed, check that you’re the team agent and that the app is in one of the statuses that allow the app to be deleted.
- A confirmation dialog appears. Click Delete.

Reference : [Transferring And Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: not helpful, nor even close. you just copied and pasted from the apple website. doesnt attempt to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @HomelessPeopleCanCode: Did you read the first portion of my answer ? I added apple content as a reference. First read the question and answer completely then comment. Also read the discussion happened with me and op through comments.